# puppeteer form fill-up date field is filled without year

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have form which I wanted to fill using puppeteer and after filling and submitting  I want to exports result to PDF , I am facing problem in filling date as puppeteer is filling day and month of date field but year is left blank and puppeteer submits the form because of this puppeteer is exporting page to PDF with existing results which is incomplete

codes I have tried is to long but for understanding I am attaching Two Images what I want and what I am Getting
what I want is this two Image
[image: 1st Image]

[image: Second Image]

and what I am Getting is this one image
[image]

```js
function ajax11(){
        var vesselname=document.getElementById('vesselname');
        var date=document.getElementById('date');
        var fdata="vesselname="+vesselname.value+"&date="+date.value;
        var submitbutton=document.getElementById("submitbutton");
        var main=document.getElementById("main");
        var dataarra=[];
        //var xhttp;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                myObj=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                myObj1=myObj.results;
                myObj1.forEach((myObj1,index)=>{
                    var d1=document.createElement("div");
                    d1.setAttribute("class","w3-container w3-bottombar w3-topbar w3-leftbar w3-rightbar w3-border-grey");
                    d1.setAttribute("style","padding-top: 0.5%; padding-bottom: 0.5%;");
                    d1.setAttribute("name","datacontainer");
                    d1.setAttribute("id","datacontainer");
                    main.appendChild(d1);
                    //document.body.appendChild(d1);
                    var d5=document.createElement("div");
                    var table1=document.createElement("table");
                    var table1tehad=document.createElement("thead");
                    var table1tehadtr1=document.createElement("tr");
                    var table1tehadtr2=document.createElement("tr");
                    var table1tehadtr1th1=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr1th2=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th1=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th2=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th3=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th4=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th5=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th6=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th7=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th8=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th9=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th10=document.createElement("th");
                    var table1tehadtr2th11=document.createElement("th");
                    d5.setAttribute("class","w3-cell-row");
                    table1.setAttribute("class","w3-table");
                    table1tehadtr1th1.setAttribute("colspan","7");
                    table1tehadtr1th2.setAttribute("colspan","3");
                    table1tehadtr1th2.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-center w3-blue-grey");
                    table1tehadtr2.setAttribute("class","w3-blue-grey");
                    table1tehadtr2th1.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th2.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th3.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th4.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th5.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th6.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th7.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    table1tehadtr2th8.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    table1tehadtr2th9.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    table1tehadtr2th10.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    table1tehadtr2th11.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    d1.appendChild(d5);
                    d5.appendChild(table1);
                    table1.appendChild(table1tehad);
                    table1tehad.appendChild(table1tehadtr1);
                    table1tehad.appendChild(table1tehadtr2);
                    table1tehadtr1.appendChild(table1tehadtr1th1);
                    table1tehadtr1.appendChild(table1tehadtr1th2);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th1);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th2);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th3);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th4);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th5);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th6);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th7);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th8);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th9);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th10);
                    table1tehadtr2.appendChild(table1tehadtr2th11);
                    table1tehadtr1th1.innerHTML="Vessel Name:- "+vesselname.value+" Shiftwise Loading Details";
                    table1tehadtr1th2.innerText="Quantity";
                    table1tehadtr2th1.innerText="Shipper Name";
                    table1tehadtr2th2.innerText="Invoice No";
                    table1tehadtr2th3.innerText="Job No";
                    table1tehadtr2th4.innerText="S/Bill No";
                    table1tehadtr2th5.innerText="Packing";
                    table1tehadtr2th6.innerText="Net";
                    table1tehadtr2th7.innerText="Gross";
                    table1tehadtr2th8.innerText="Bags";
                    table1tehadtr2th9.innerText="Nmt";
                    table1tehadtr2th10.innerText="Gmt";
                    table1tehadtr2th11.innerText="Hatch No";
                    var tbodytable1=document.createElement("tbody");
                    var tbodytable1tr=document.createElement("tr");
                    var tbodytable1trtd1=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd2=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd3=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd4=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd5=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd6=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd7=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd8=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd9=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd10=document.createElement("td");
                    var tbodytable1trtd11=document.createElement("td");
                    tbodytable1trtd3.setAttribute("onclick","ajax12(this)");
                    tbodytable1tr.setAttribute("class","w3-pale-blue");
                    tbodytable1trtd1.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd2.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd3.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd4.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd5.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd6.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd7.setAttribute("class","w3-border");
                    tbodytable1trtd8.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    tbodytable1trtd9.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    tbodytable1trtd10.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-blue-grey");
                    tbodytable1trtd11.setAttribute("class","w3-border w3-center");
                    tbodytable1trtd1.innerText=myObj1.shipper_name;
                    tbodytable1trtd2.innerText=myObj1.shippinginv;
                    tbodytable1trtd3.innerText=myObj1.jobno;
                    tbodytable1trtd4.innerText=myObj1.shippingbillno;
                    tbodytable1trtd5.innerText=myObj1.packing;
                    tbodytable1trtd6.innerText=myObj1.Net;
                    tbodytable1trtd7.innerText=myObj1.bagsweigh;
                    tbodytable1trtd8.innerText=myObj1.bags;
                    tbodytable1trtd9.innerText=myObj1.netweigh;
                    tbodytable1trtd10.innerText=myObj1.grossweigh;
                    tbodytable1trtd11.innerText=myObj1.Hatch_No;
                    table1.appendChild(tbodytable1);
                    tbodytable1.appendChild(tbodytable1tr);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd1);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd2);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd3);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd4);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd5);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd6);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd7);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd8);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd9);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd10);
                    tbodytable1tr.appendChild(tbodytable1trtd11);
                    tbodytable1trtd3.click();
                    tbodytable1trtd3.removeAttribute("onclick","ajax12(this)");
                    submitbutton.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
                });
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST","/ajax11",true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhttp.send(fdata);
    }
```

this is only half of codes which get data from database and creates first Table and on basis of this first Table Second Ajax Call Triggers and creates another three tables

Comment: Not including long code is right, but to debug your issue we'd at least need html code for the date selector and a piece of your code that is entering a date. Otherwise it's impossible to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please add some of your code.

Comment: I am trying to add date like this await page.$eval('input[name=date]', e=>e.setAttribute("value",date));